locally projective module is projective
This question arises from the Exercise III-41 of the book The Geometry of Schemes. Let me state it first:
Exercise III-41. A submodule of a finitely generated free module that is locally a direct summand is in fact a direct summand.
My approach. I tried to approach it with the "local-global" property of a split exact sequence, i.e. a short exact sequence splits iff the localization at each prime is exact. Some finiteness condition is required but luckily we have it here:
Consider $$0\to K\to T^n\to coker\to 0$$
where $K$ is the finitely generated submodule that is locally a direct summand of free module. Since we have $$0\to K_\mathfrak{q}\to T_\mathfrak{q}^n\to coker_\mathfrak{q}\to 0$$
a split short exact sequence, and $coker$ a finitely presented (as $K$ is finitely generated), we conclude the proof. I feel like this approach is an overkill, and I do not understand anything out of it.
Question. Can anyone give a proof without using projective resolution, $Ext$ etc.? Any help is appreciated!

One obvious approach is to follow Serre's proof that locally free implies projective. Another option would be to take the splitting maps and glue them up, maybe? (It seems kind of annoying to have to do the whole of Serre's proof, but every time I try to avoid the length of that proof, things go poorly.) Also: "a short exact sequence splits iff the localization at each prime is exact" is not true.

Thank you! I will check Serre's proof on that. I realize the claim is NOT true and some finiteness condition must be estabilished. One condition I saw is finitely presented, as explained here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271588/local-property-of-split-exact-sequence
